to call parameterized onclick function in html why use string format?
to call parameterized onclick function in html why use string formate?
<td><button onclick="deleteArticle(this,'<%= article.articleId %>')">Delete</button></td>
<script>
        async function deleteArticle(e,id){           
            const response = await fetch(`/article/delete/${id}`);
            const data = JSON.parse(await response.json());            
            if(data.message == 'ok'){
                alert('Record deleted successfully');
                const parentNode = e.parentNode.parentNode;
                parentNode.remove();
            }
            else if(message.response=='error'){
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    </script>


Because the article ID is a string.
